# How to prevent state from resetting when calling a state setter in a 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm trying to convert a React class component into a React function component.

There is an `onChange` function that is called both inside the component and from outside.
When calling a function component function, the `useState` hook takes the initial value. When I'm using the old class component way, everything works correctly. Why is this happening, and how to solve this problem?

```js
const MyInput = (props) => {
  const { someLib, ...otherProps } = props;
  const [test, setTest] = useState(1); // console show 1,2,3, etc
            
  useEffect(() => {
    someLib && someLib.addCallback(onChange);
  }, []);

  const onChange = (event) => { 
    setTest(test + 1) // this function can called inside MyInput, and from someLib, 
                      // when it called from someLib, 'test' is reset, but in class component everything good 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `onChange` is a stale closure. What you need to do is make `onChange` look like this:

```js
const onChange = (event) => {
    setTest(oldTest => oldTest +1)
}
```

Alternatively you could add `test` to the dependency array in your `useEffect` make sure to do cleanup though. (You should be doing this anyways but it is even more important now)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    someLib && someLib.addCallback(onChange);

    return () => {
        someLib.removeCallback(onChange);
    }
}, [someLib, test]);
```

technically if you are doing this latter method you would want to `useCallback`

```js
const onChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setTest(test + 1);
}, [test]);

useEffect(() => {
    someLib && someLib.addCallback(onChange);

    return () => {
        someLib.removeCallback(onChange);
    }
}, [someLib, onChange]);
```

the benefit of this is that you don't have to keep track of the dependencies of `onChange` in a different place. The dependency list for `onChange` is now close.

Comment: Use `someLib?.` (conditional chaining) for both the add and remove of the callback.